# Как я могу выполнять запросы от имени прокси-сервера через node-fetch? (NodeJS)

Tags: ajax, node.js, proxy, fetch

Для работы с апи на сервере я использую пакет node-fetch. Мне нужно иногда выполнять запросы через мои прокси сервера вида (ip:port:login:password), но я не понимаю как мне это сделать через данный пакет или лучше использовать что то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку node-fetch сам по себе не поддерживает прокси, можешь попробовать использовать https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-http-proxy-agent

Выглядеть код будет примерно таким образом

```
fetch('ссылка', {agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://ip:port:login:password')})
    .then((res) => ...)
```